# Scikit-learn and pyspark integration

Tags: python, apache-spark, scikit-learn, pyspark

I have trained a logistic regression model in sklearn and saved the model to .pkl files. Is there a method of using this pkl file from within spark?

Comment: What do you mean with "from within spark"? Does the answer from Yaron already address your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are using spark shouldn't hold you from using external python libraries.

You can import sklearn library in your spark-python code, and use sklearn logistic regression model with the saved pkl file.